# Elements in array without keys mixed with elements with keys

Tags: php

I've stumbled upon this function today:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
    ];
}
```

I don't understand this construction:

`['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]`

How's that first two entries have only value, and the third has a key and a value. Is it something that PHP language allows?

Comment: The `key` is optional. If it is not specified, PHP will use the increment of the largest previously used integer key.. So actually your array looks like as `[0 => 'status', 1 => 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]`

Comment: @Uchiha, thanks. Would you say it's a bad practice to not specify keys for all elements? And as I understand also mixing integer keys with string isn't  a good idea as well?

Comment: Nope that's not a bad practice, as keys are optional its on user to define keys for his own so he can access it directly defining its key like as over here you can simply call your defined key `value` like as `$your_array[0]['value']`

Comment: I'd argue that it *is* bad practice, as it can make traversing the data structure difficult later, since it conflates the concepts of an ordered list and an unordered map. In practice it's often cleaner to separate these two idioms of traversing a collection. But whatever floats your boat, you may find a practical use for it...

Comment: @deceze, yes, that's exactly what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing new. Key is just optional. You can find a similar case in the very first example of the PHP documentation for arrays.

Here it is.

```
<?php
$fruits = array (
    "fruits"  => array("a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple"),
    "numbers" => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    "holes"   => array("first", 5 => "second", "third")
);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php